# node.js: The POST method in my RESTAPI does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I start learning Node.js and Express.js and I'm trying to create a simple API to list data from JSON file (using the GET method) and add a new user using the POST method.

the GET method works fine but the POST method does not work

when I request `http://127.0.0.1:8080/listusers` the API sends all users in a JSON file.
when I request `http://127.0.0.1:8080/adduser` the API has to add new User Info and send the new data back to the browser.

> NOTE: I read all the questions on Stackoverflow about this problem but
> non of them help me so I have to ask again.

the problem is when I request `http://127.0.0.1:8080/adduser` I get the following error

```
Cannot GET /adduser
```

here is the `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var user = {
        "user4" : {
               "name" : "mounir",
       "password" : "password4",
       "profession" : "teacher",
       "id": 4
    }
};

app.post('/adduser', function (req, res) {
        // First read existing users.
        fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
               data = JSON.parse( data );
               data["user4"] = user["user4"];
               console.log( data );
       res.end(JSON.stringify(data) );
    });
});

app.get('/listusers', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        res.end(data);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("listening at http://%s:%s", "0.0.0.0", port)
});
```

Comment: How are you making your post request?

Comment: Are you trying to access the URL through the URL Bar of your browser? If so, that sends a GET request, **not** a POST request

Comment: @MichaelM. to make this work I have to add a form in an index.html so the request can be send as POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the error.  Cannot GET /adduser.  Keyword GET!  If you are making a post request, be sure you include the appropriate headers and that you are making a POST request, with a body, and not a GET request.  For instance if you are using fetch:

```js
const myInit = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: {
    ...
  }
};

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/adduser", myInit)
  .then(res => {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: I am still a beginner at node.js can you explain your code to me, please!

Comment: You have to send the post request somehow from the client(front-end).  Built in methods like fetch can do the job, or 3rd party libraries like axios.  One important thing to remember is to set the "method" to POST, not GET, and for post requests, you typically include a body as that is the only way you can include the data that is to be stored through the post request.  I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Often times the data to be sent via post request is collected with a form on the front-end.  Collect input from the user, then send a POST request to your api, with the input from the user as the body.

Comment: Thank you I got it now i will try to add a form or use postman to send a POST request to myAPI

Comment: Exactly! Good Luck!